# How can I make sure my bottle cap is sealed tightly?

Tags: beer, bottling, carbonation

I have concerns over why our beers are not carbonating properly. One [suggestion](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/341/why-is-our-beer-not-carbonating/344) was to check and make sure the bottles are sealed properly. What might be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick check would be to stretch a rubber balloon over the neck of your bottle after capping. If the cap is not sealed the balloon will slowly inflate.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a butterfly capper, check to make sure you're pressing hard enough. There should be a slight ring-shaped indentation in the cap after capping a bottle.

An easy way to check once they're capped is to simply store a few upside down. If there's a leak, the gas will bring some beer with it as it leaks out the cap.

Comment: I've heard that storing beer bottles tipped or upside down can cause strange tastes due to the cap deteriorating.

Answer (score 1):

There are Go / No-go guages that are used in industry for online checks to ensure a  tight crimp on a crown. Failing this immerssion on a a water bath will quickly show if you have leakers. The folks who make the crowns will provide the data on what a tight crimp should be. hope this helps